# Paypal 500 error when creating payout

Tags: node.js, paypal

I'm using `paypal-rest-sdk` with node.js, attempting to create PayPal payouts.  I've reproduced my calling code here:

```
paypal.payout.create({
sender_batch_header: {
    sender_batch_id: batchId,
    email_subject: 'Payment Received',
},
items: [{
    recipient_type: 'EMAIL',
    amount: {
        currency: 'USD',
        value: bid.bidPrice / 2,
    },
    receiver: provider.email,
}],
}, 'true', {}, function (err, response) {
debugger;
// inspect err
});
```

The response I get from PayPal is a 500 error.  `err.response` from above, is this object:

```
{
name: 'INTERNAL_ERROR',
message: 'An internal service error has occurred.',
debug_id: '5053046dcea3',
information_link: 'https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_ERROR',
httpStatusCode: 500
}
```

I did google the `debug_id` but it turns out it's just a Paypal-internal ID for the error that happened.

I'm not if I'm calling PayPal's services incorrectly, or if they are just having trouble.  I did submit a support ticket to PayPal.  Any other actions I could take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're seeing an HTTP 500 or INTERNAL_ERROR message, you've encountered a bug in PayPal.

Please contact [Merchant Technical Support](https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask) with the request/response. (Most important is the `debug_id`.)